# C++ error: passing xxx as 'this' argument of xxx discards qualifiers

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, friend-function

This is the code I've written to access a matrix in a class and compare two objects of the same class using less than operator and equal to operator. But the compiler throws errors.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

class node {
private:
  int a[5][5];

public:
  int& operator()(int i, int j) {
    return a[i][j];
  }

  friend bool operator==(const node& one, const node& two);
  friend bool operator<(const node& one, const node& two);
};

bool operator==(const node& one, const node& two) {
  for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j < 5; j++) {
      if (one(i, j) != two(i, j)) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
}

bool operator<(const node& one, const node& two) {
  for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j < 5; j++) {
      if (one(i, j) > two(i, j)) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
}

int main() {
  node src;
  for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j < 5; j++) {
      cin >> src(i, j);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The compile time error is:

```
code.cpp: In function 'bool operator==(const node&, const node&)':
code.cpp:20:19: error: passing 'const node' as 'this' argument of 'int& node::operator()(int, int)' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
       if (one(i, j) != two(i, j)) {
                   ^
code.cpp:20:32: error: passing 'const node' as 'this' argument of 'int& node::operator()(int, int)' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
       if (one(i, j) != two(i, j)) {
                                ^
code.cpp: In function 'bool operator<(const node&, const node&)':
code.cpp:31:19: error: passing 'const node' as 'this' argument of 'int& node::operator()(int, int)' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
       if (one(i, j) > two(i, j)) {
                   ^
code.cpp:31:31: error: passing 'const node' as 'this' argument of 'int& node::operator()(int, int)' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
       if (one(i, j) > two(i, j)) {
```

Can someone tell me where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
const int operator()(int i, int j) const {
  return a[i][j];
}
```

Comment: Adding this resulted in a different error.
`error: cannot bind 'std::istream {aka std::basic_istream<char>}' lvalue to 'std::basic_istream<char>&&'
       cin >> src(i, j);`

Comment: @ksharma377 corrected